# Configure Raspberry Pi as WIFI Access Point / Hotspot / File Server

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, access-point

So I have a Raspberry PI set up as an access point and I can connect to it as if it was a router to share an internet connection.

just like explained here: http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-WiFi-Access-Point-out-of-a-Raspberry/

Now all I want this for is just so I can access files from the RPi and transfer them to other devices.

The question is how can I (after a device connected the RPi via WiFi) access files from the RPi?

Comment: Maybe install an FTP server or Apache and get the files from there?

Answer (score 1):

You can install any number of server applications to share files, like FTP or HTTP. If you want to share files with computers running Microsoft Windows® the best bet would probably be SAMBA. To do this from the command line, try the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common-bin
```

and then after it's installed you need to edit the configuration:

```
sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Uncomment the line that says `# security = user` by removing the `#` from the beginning of the line. You also need to find where it says `read only = yes` in the `[homes]` section and change it to `read only = no`. Press `[CTRL]+X` to exit nano and press `y` to save.

Then restart the SAMBA service with the new configuration:

```
sudo service samba restart
```

Finally, you have to add a password for each user. for the default user `pi` just enter:

```
sudo smbpasswd -a pi
```

Repeat the above command for each user you wish to add.

You should now be able to access your Pi's files from your Windows computer by navigating to it just like any other shared folder: `\\raspberrypi\pi` or in my case I have to use the IP address because of my network setup `\\192.168.0.209\pi`

[image: Raspberry Pi SAMBA Setup]